# Replace small expressions in larger expressions?

Tags: replacement, expression-manipulation

How can I replace small expressions in larger expressions?

**Simple example**

`Replace[a^2 + b^2 + 2*a*b + x, (a + b)^2 -> c]`

I want to get `c + x` but the output is `a^2 + b^2 + 2*a*b + x`.

Comment: `Replace` does only literal replacements. Try `Simplify[a^2 + b^2 + 2*a*b + x, Assumptions -> (a + b)^2 == c]` instead.

Comment: An algebraic approach: `Last@PolynomialReduce[a^2 + b^2 + 2*a*b + x, {(a + b)^2 - c}, {a, b, c, x}]`.  (The goal of `PolynomialReduce` is not replacement, and, while it works here, it may not work in every instance. OTOH, depending on what the general goal is, if there is a more general goal, it may be more appropriate than replacement, since it is a quite common algebraic operation.)  With a similar caveat, there's also `First@GroebnerBasis[{a^2 + b^2 + 2*a*b + x, (a + b)^2 - c}, {c, x}, {a, b}]`

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

First:

```
s = Solve[(a + b)^2 == c, a][[1, 1]]

(*  a -> -b - Sqrt[c]  *)
```

second:

```
a^2 + b^2 + 2*a*b + x /. s // Simplify

(*  c + x   *)
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

A simple method:

```
   a^2 + b^2 + 2*a*b + x /. Expand[(a + b)^2 -> c]
```